# Error "$flutterSdkpath\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle" while running the app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing an issue while running the app.
My flutter details are:

Flutter Version: 1.12.13+hotfilx.9

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1098], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

While running the flutter run in visual studio it is showing this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH1859 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'project_name\android\settings.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not read script '\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Even I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Flutter projects created on the master channel will generate an `android/settings.gradle` file that points to a file in the Flutter tool that's present in 1.18.0-dev.5.0 ([currently available on all channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)).

Switching from master -> stable "downgrades" Flutter relative to that change, and the file is no longer present.

You can work around this by regenerating your `android/settings.gradle` while on stable:

```
$ rm android/settings.gradle
$ flutter create .
```

See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55619) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped

Comment: by mistake I run this comment and I lost my all codes without backup. Can I return to previous code by command line

Comment: No, @AbirAhsan, you cannot recover a previous state of the code: if it hasn't been saved with some version control it has been overwritten and it's lost.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace the current  setting.gradle file code with you wanna running  version project setting.gradle.
e.g:
Other version project :
android>setting.gradle

This code will be your current flutter version just replace your setting.gradle with old one or other project

**Settings.gradle**

```
include ':app' 

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
   pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
   def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
   include ":$name"
   project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Better include the code here as text instead of posting as image.

Comment: @Sahibzada Siraj,  Your suggestion helped me to fix my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just downgrade the recent library/package you used and you'll be just fine

Answer (score 0):

Changing the channel from **stable** to **master** worked for me.

To view the channel :

```
flutter channel
```

To change the channel :

```
flutter channel <channel_name>
```

e.g. `flutter channel master`

Answer (score 0):

JUST go to the path sdk flutter path

`$flutterPath\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle`

and ensure the file app_plugin_loader is there, if not restore it from recycle bin or download it

Comment: Language is important. Answer should be understood by everyone

Answer (score 0):

you know sometimes the only thing you must do is `flutter clean` and after that `flutter pub get` :) this is how i solved the issue. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue on a Mac (like I was), there is a possibility that VS Code **does not have access** to the Flutter SDK folder.

One simple fix is to run: `sudo flutter run`

The second option is to simply provide access to VS Code in the **Privacy & Security** section in Settings.